# Dont ou de laquelle ? Quel pronom relatif utiliser ?

Tags: grammaire, phrase

Bonjour à tous, pouvez-vous m'aider ? La deuxième option est-elle correcte ou seulement la première ?

1. J'ai acheté ce collier dans une boutique dont j'ai oublié l'adresse
2. J'ai acheté ce collier dans une boutique l'adresse de laquelle j'ai oublié

Answer (score 4):

La phrase n° 2 est « inouïe » (au sens propre).

Elle serait plus grammaticale en mettant une virgule après *boutique* mais la tournure n'en reste pas moins totalement non idiomatique.

Au mieux, on pourrait essayer d'écrire :

> J'ai acheté ce collier dans une boutique, boutique *de laquelle* j'ai oublié l'adresse.

mais ça reste très inhabituel.

On n'aurait au contraire pas pu utiliser *dont* dans une phrase comme :

> J'ai acheté ce collier dans une boutique près *de laquelle* j'habite.

Comment: Makes you curious why *duquel*, etc. exist at all. Can you give examples where they clearly trump *dont* ?

Comment: As in Jlliagre's last example, with a prepositional phrase ending in de: près de, à côté de, en face de, etc. You cannot use "dont" for these, you need près duquel, à côte duquel, en face duquel, etc.